# wxwidget application crashes on exit, when I add code to do drag and drop

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, wxwidgets

I have a wxwidget application that uses dragandrop and when I close the application, it crashes on this line:

```
virtual ~wxDropTargetBase()
    { delete m_dataObject; }
```

I setup the drapand drop in this way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : MainWindowTemplate(NULL), m_fileDropTarget(textSourceFolder)
{
    // connect events
    this->Connect(wxEVT_IDLE, wxIdleEventHandler(MainWindow::OnIdle));
    // set window minimum size - work around bug that ignores outer border and sets min size slightly too small
    wxSize minSize = sizerOuter->GetMinSize();
    minSize.SetWidth(minSize.GetWidth() + 16);
    minSize.SetHeight(minSize.GetHeight() + 16);
    SetMinSize(minSize);
    Layout();
    // set file drop target
    SetDropTarget(&m_fileDropTarget);
}
```

and the source code for my

```
class MyFileDropTarget : public wxFileDropTarget
{
public:
    MyFileDropTarget(wxTextCtrl *textCtrl)
    {
        m_fileTextCtrl = textCtrl;
    }
    virtual bool wxFileDropTarget::OnDropFiles (wxCoord x, wxCoord y, const wxArrayString &filenames)
    {
        if (filenames.size() > 0)
        {
            m_fileTextCtrl->SetValue(filenames.Item(0));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    wxTextCtrl *m_fileTextCtrl;
};
```

what is the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `m_fileDropTarget` is an object, in which case it is deleted twice, as when you call `SetDropTarget()` it takes ownership of the pointer passed to it.